# Ruby on rails -How to write a definition that should be executed when we make a call to the controller irrespective of method called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

in a rubyonrails application i want to do an updation to the database irrespective of the method called.
take "update" be the common definition.

if am calling a method import, the controller should execute the code in definition of import method and also the common update method.

```
class Admin::ReportsController < ApplicationController


def update

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  #index.html.erb
    end
  end

def index

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  #index.html.erb
    end
  end



def import

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  #index.html.erb
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you clarify with an example?

Comment: your example code is probably wrong, if you called both `update` and another method you would get a `DoubleRenderException`, but as JRL wrote, a filter is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that's a bit more clear.

the answer is that you can add methods to controllers that can be used in multiple actions eg:

```
class Admin::ReportsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @objects = get_objects

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  #index.html.erb
    end
  end

  def import
    @objects = get_objects

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  #index.html.erb
    end
  end

  # using protected means that the methods below here won't be recognised as new actions
 protected
 def get_objects
    unless params[:my_objects].present?
       flash[:notice] = "no objects!"
       return redirect_to(:action => :index)
    end
    objects = []
    params[:objects].each do |obj|
       objects << object.new(obj)
    end
    objects

 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a [before filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) to the controller. e.g.:

```
before_filter :common_update_method
```